# IOS drop down with UITextField and UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, drop-down-menu, uitextfield

I have created a drop down using UITextField and UITableView. When the user selects a textfield then a tableview is displayed as a drop down. I had set the tableview delegate and datasource in another class.

Now my issue is i wanted to get the text of the selected row in tableview on to the textfield i.e I want to send the tableview row text back to view controller(which consists of textfield) when user selects a row in tableview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you create a delegate yourself?

Comment: u mean instead of tableview delegate create other custom delegate?

Comment: No no, create a separate delegate that will pass the selected row text back to the VC which contains your textfield.

Comment: oh kk. I haven't thought in that way i must give it a try. I will try in that way but Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Or just pass the VC reference to the tableview delegate instance and call an appropriate method implemented in your VC class whenever the row is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add below code in In view did load of class in which you have added UITextField

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addValueToTextField:) name:@"addValueToTextFiel" object:nil]; 

-(void)addValueToTextField:(NSNotification *) notification{
      NSString* text = [notification text];

       yourTextField.text = text;
}
```

And in Didselect delegate of UITable view of other class you have to add following code

```
 UITableViewCell *selectedCell =[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"addValueToTextField" object:nil userInfo:selectedCell.Text];
```

Or alternate of its is you can use custom delegates

Answer (score 1):

Create custom delegate for controller with UITableView

ItemsList .h file

```
@protocol ItemsListDelegate : NSObject
@optional
- (void)itemSelected:(int)num withTitle:(NSString *)title;
@end

@interface ItemsList : UITableViewController{
id <ItemsListDelegate> delegate;
...
}
```

ItemsList .m file

```
#import "ItemsList.h"

@implementation ItemsList<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
@synthesize delegate;

.....

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
[delegate itemsSelected:[indexPath row] withTitle:[items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];
}

.....
```

And in ViewController with your field set in .h

```
#import "ItemsList.h"

@interface ViewWithField<ItemsListDelegate>{
ItemsList *itemsList;
}

....
```

And in .m file

```
.....

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    itemList.delegate = self;
}

- (void)itemSelected:(int)num withTitle:(NSString *)title{
    self.textField.text = title;
}
.....
```

Something like this. I don't check errors in this code. But look at this way.
Or use NotificationCenter, but this way is more correct.

Sorry for my ugly English.